# Почему сбрасываются ссылки в редакторе JetBrains Rider?

Tags: unity3d, jetbrains, rider

После того как в Unity происходит обновление ресурсов, в IDE происходит сбрасывание ссылок

Unity 2021.1.25f1

Rider 2021.2.2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Rider не умеет записывать изменения в assembly difinision в Unity
Найдите нужную assembly difinision и укажите ссылку в ручную